# How to display a JSON response on separate lines using jQuery and PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I am using AJAX to submit a form, and would like to display a summary of the information on the page so that the user can confirm the information before submitting. I am having trouble getting the results to display on multiple lines. Any suggestions on the best way to do this?

Here is the PHP:

```
$return['message'] = 'First Entry: ' . $_POST['Name1'] . ' '  . 'Second Entry: ' .    $_POST['Name2'] . ' ' . 'Third Entry: ' . $_POST['Name3'];  

echo json_encode($return);
```

Here is the jQuery:

```
$("#mark-form").validate({
    submitHandler: function(form) {
            $(form).ajaxSubmit({                  
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    "Name1" : $('#Name1').val(),
                    "Name2" : $('#Name2').val(),
                    "Name3" : $('#Name3').val()
                       },
                dataType: 'json',
                url: './includes/ajaxtest3.php',
                error: function() {alert("Error");},
                success: 
                function(data) {
                    $('<div id="output2"></div>').insertAfter($('#agreement-information'));
                    $('#output2').html(data.message).show(500);
                    $('#ouput2').append(data);  
                },       
  });

return false;   
   },
        errorPlacement: function(error,element) {
                        return true;
                },
        rules: {
            "Name1": {
                required: true,
                }
        }       
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can transfer JSON encoded HTML newlines like this:

```
$return['message'] = 'First Entry: ' . $_POST['Name1'] . '<br /> '  . 'Second Entry: ' .    $_POST['Name2'] . '<br /> ' . 'Third Entry: ' . $_POST['Name3'];  
echo json_encode($return);
```

Or convert newlines (\n) into newline tags.

The nicer way though would be to leave that kind of processing to the client by e.g. returning an array of messages:

```
$return['message'] = array();
$return['message'][] = 'First Entry: ' . $_POST['Name1'];
$return['message'][] = 'Second Entry: ' . $_POST['Name2'];
$return['message'][] = 'Third Entry: ' . $_POST['Name3'];
echo json_encode($return);
```

And leave the processing to the client (maybe the client wants the messages wrapped in a paragraph tag later on):

```
function(data)
{
    $('<div id="output2"></div>').insertAfter($('#agreement-information'));
    $('#output2').html(data.message.join('<br />')).show(500);
    $('#ouput2').append(data);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally you want to use `json_encode` on arrays. So your PHP array would look like:

```
$arr = array('foo' => 1, 'bar' => 2, 'baz' => 'test');
// you can probably just use $_POST here, i.e. $arr = $_POST

echo json_encode($arr);
```

And your JavaScript dealing with that `data` variable would look like this:

```
$('#id').html(data.foo + "<br />" + data.bar + "<br />" + data.baz);
```

This lets you deal with your data piecewise, rather than in one lump, so it's easier to manipulate and parse.

Answer (score 0):

You need to insert `<br />` tags or insert `\n` and then put the content in `pre` tag. Remeber you are injecting this content into an html DOM so html rules still apply :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
$return['message'] = 'First Entry: ' . $_POST['Name1'] . '<br />'  . 'Second Entry: ' .    $_POST['Name2'] . '<br />' . 'Third Entry: ' . $_POST['Name3'];
```